# Xpath select nodes where parent has some attribute

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I have a problem using xpath.
I need to select all items from category.
Something like (pseudo lang.):
select all divs if **class != block-events-head** and parent attribute **data-category-sport="Basketball"**

here is html sample:

```
<div data-category-sport="Basketball" data-category-treeid="972911">
<div class="block-events-head">...</div>
<div id="event_1558960" data-event-treeid="1558960">...</div>
<div id="event_1559240" data-event-treeid="1559240">...</div>
<div id="event_1559560" data-event-treeid="1559560">...</div>
</div>
```

Im trying:

```
.//div[@class!="block-events-head" and ../div[@data-category-sport='Basketball']]
```

But it not works :(

```
.//div[@class!="block-events-head"]
```

works but how to add a "filter by parent"?

Help me to solve please..

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of your XPath expression is that the second term `../div[@data-category-sport='Basketball']` is also true for all the siblings of the nodes for which the first term `@class!="block-events-head"` holds. What you want is that both parts of the condition are checked for the same parent-child relationship. This is actually pretty easy to achieve. Just move the check for the parent to a higher level of the hierarchy

```
.//div[@data-category-sport='Basketball']/div[@class!="block-events-head"]
```

and see if this works for you.

Comment: @theTech beat me by 7 seconds... :-)

Comment: Im trying .//div[@data-category-sport='Basketball']/div[@class!="block-events-head"] it not works :( But. If i write .//div[@data-category-sport='Basketball']/div[@class="block-events-head"] it works an give me all elements whree class="block-events-head" and parent has needed attribute :( Why? Is it possible becouse items has no class attribute yet? (exampl. <div id="event_1558960" data-event-treeid="1558960">)

Comment: Solved! .//div[@data-category-sport='Basketball']/*[@id!=""] =) Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if is this what you want, but see if this helps you somehow:

> .//div[@data-category-sport="Basketball"]/div[@class!="block-events-head"]